# Modalから値を受け取る処理

Tags: ios, swift

いつもお世話になってます
今、iPadアプリの開発をしています。
親ビューからモーダルで数値入力をした後、親ビューへ値を返すのはどのようにしたらいいでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

delegateを使って値の引き渡しをしようと考えたのですが、

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

でモーダルを消すと親ビューの方の

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
```

が動いてくれませんでした。

Comment: デリゲートを使って値を引き渡す準備はどこまでできていますか？ 例えばモーダルの方で、デリゲートメソッドやデリゲートを保持するプロパティーの宣言はできているでしょうか？　`viewWillAppear` はそのタイミングで呼ばれるメソッドではないので呼ばれませんし、値の受け渡しにも関係ない／不要だと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

モーダルでは、`UIViewController`のプロパティ`presentingViewController`で、「親」ViewControllerを取得できます。

親ViewControllerを`ViewController`とし、モーダルを閉じた時の処理を行うメソッド`doAnything()`が実装されているとします。ボタンアクション`closeModal()`でモーダルを閉じます。

```
@IBAction func closeModal(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let controller = self.presentingViewController as? ViewController {
        controller.doAnything()
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

`doAnything()`に引数を定義するとか、プロパティと置き換えるとかすれば、変数の受け渡しが可能になります。
しかし、Navigation Controllerがあるなど、View Controllerが多層状態の場合、`presentingViewController`は、基底（いちばん下の）View Controllerを返しますから、期待どおりの結果になりません。単にNavigation Controllerだけがあるのなら、

```
@IBAction func closeModal(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let navigationController = self.presentingViewController as? UINavigationController,
    let controller = navigationController.topViewController as? ViewController {
        controller.doAnything()
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

と書きかえればすみますが、より汎用的な記述を求めるなら、
(1) Delegateを実装する。
(2) Storyboardで、Unwind Segueを利用する。
が考えられます。（*さらに回答をお求めなら、質問文を更新して、どういう方針でいきたいか、明記してもらえると、それに対して回答する用意はあります*）

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。親ViewControllerの上にNavigation Controllerがある場合はどのように書き換えたらいいでしょうか？